# Looking for an event based flash based video player (java script)

Tags: javascript, flash, events, video

I need a flash based video player that is able to trigger events I can listen to via JavaScript. The events I need to listen to are:

- The play button is pressed
- The pause
  button is pressed
- The video stops (is
  finished)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the http://www.longtailvideo.com/

and for specifics on event listeners, see http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#settinglisteneres

Comment: Looks good! We will decide between JW Player and Flowplayer (http://flowplayer.org/documentation/events/player.html) - thank you!